# Setting textbox value using js function?

Tags: javascript

There are two textfields, both of them will take nuber as input. they are: 
1) number of contents
2) number of words

input boxes for collecting this values are provided respectively.

```
<input type="text" id="A1" data-msg-required="Please enter the subject." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="ncontent" id="subject">

<input type="text" id="B1" onchange="valueCalculate()" data-format="0" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter the subject." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="nword" id="subject">
```

depending on the of the first textbox, the value of third textbox will be changed. (which is hidden)

```
<input type="hidden" id="C1" data-format="$ 0,0[.]00"  maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="" id="subject">
```

The script i have written is:

```
<script>
        function valueCalculate() {
            var contentNum = document.getElementById("A1").value;
            alert(contentNum);
            var noOfWords = document.getElementById("B1").value;
            alert(noOfWords);
            var rate = document.getElementById("C1");
            rate.value = 0;
            if (contentNum < 5) {
                rate.value = 0.03;
            } else if (contentNum > 4 && contentNum < 15) {
                rate.value = 0.027;
            } else if (contentNum > 14 && contentNum < 26) {
                rate.value = 0.024;
            } else {
                rate.value = 0.020;
            }
            alert(rate.value);
            var final = contentNum * numOfWords * rate.value;

        }
    </script>
```

after this, depending on the value of third hidden textbox, the value of fourth textbox will be visible, which is not hidden but disabled. for a fixed value of the third box, that part works, so i am not mentioning that part here. Any help about setting up the value of third textbox will be highly appreciable.

N.B.: all alerts of script are showing value accurately.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention what the problem is.

Comment: "Any help about setting up the value of third textbox will be highly appreciable."
if the value is fixed, then it is working. but depending on the value of first textbox, the value of the third textbox should change. i failed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you're trying to do ?

```
window.onload = function(){

var A1 = document.getElementById("A1");
//var B1 = document.getElementById("B1");

A1.addEventListener("keyup", valueCalculate);

}
```

Comment: what is understand is, window.onload executes, when the window loads. but the value of the "A1" textbox will be null.
in my case,after the page loads completely, when the user will start filling up the form, s/he will enter a value in "A1" textbox, then the value of "C1" textbox will change depending on that. window.onload shouldn't work for that

Comment: Dude aaargh, you need the document to load FIRST before you can acces ANY dom element's. That's why you need the window.onload okay ?